# unexpected php behavior

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to learn php but something goes wrong...
When I use this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first PHP page</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php   

echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm supposed to just get Hello World! In stead I get: Hello World!"; ?>
However if I just take the php code, save it as a .php file and point my browser to that file it shows Hello World in big bold letters like you'd expect. I've tried it om my own computer (with apache and PHP 5.3.15 running) and on the server of my provider with the same faulty results. I've tried different browsers, different computers. I've also tried other examples from other tutorials (the above example is the most simple that goes wrong) but none of those work as they should. Reading a text file with the include() function works when I open just the .php file but returns an empty canvas when embedded in an html file. I have not yet written a word of code myself, everything is copy/paste so what can be wrong?
Try at http://www.raadvanarbeid.nl/index2.html and http://www.raadvanarbeid.nl/index2.php for the example above.

Comment: `http://www.raadvanarbeid.nl/index2.php` works for me. The .html indeed doesn't work, but that's expected because by default HTML files are not parsed by php.

Comment: Ah... So what I'm doing wrong is save the file with a .html extension in stead of php. From the tutorials i understood that you could use php code within html pages. I never understood these pages needed a php extension in stead of html.  Thanks!

Comment: That tutorial probably meant HTML code. It is however possible to let PHP also parse .html files, but that will only be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must rename your *.html* file to *.php* so the server knows it should render the file.

Comment: Thanks, I got that from PeeHaa's comment. On with the tutorials!

Comment: This answer was provided before PeeHaa's comment. Although it is not personal, you should accept an answer if this site helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be interpreted by the PHP interpreter. Thus you need a webserver to shunt it off to the PHP interpreter, and you need to name the file so that the webserver knows it's meant to be processed by the PHP interpreter. That's why the name of the file needs to end in '.php' and why you get different results when you access the file directly versus though a webserver.

Comment: I was not trying to access the file directly, always through a server (either localhost or my provider). I just named the file wrong... Thanks anyway

Comment: That would explain it: if it doesn't end in the right suffix, the webserver wouldn't know how to process it.